# Command for a question in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I like to include a "feedback question" at the end of each slide, to check that my students are following me. For that, I include code such as:

```
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{1cm}
\only<5>{\hfill\beamerbutton{How do we get last expression?}}
\only<6>{\hfill\begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true,right]{solucion}
         Using a Taylor series expansion
         $e^t = 1 + t + t^2/2! + t^3/3! + \ldots$
     \end{beamercolorbox}}
\end{overlayarea}
```

The problem with this is that I have to set manually the level of the overlay; for instance, the question above comes from a slide with four previous items.

I would like to have a new command to simplify this. I have tried,

```
\newcommand{\pregunta}[4]{%
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{1cm}
\only<#1>{{\hfill\beamerbutton} #3 }}}
\only<#2>{{\hfill
\begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true,right]{solucion}
 #4
 \end{beamercolorbox}}}
\end{overlayarea}}
```

but it just doesn't work. Ideally, I would like a command that frees me from having to pass as arguments the two overlay levels (#1, #2), so it works at the end of a slide irrespective of how many items it has (and continues to work if an item is added or removed!).

Comment: Why don't you use a new slide after the previous one?

Comment: Because I want my students to have in front of them the current slide when I ask them the feedback question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at incremental overlay specifications (section 9.6.4 of the beamer manual).  You could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\pregunta}[2]{%
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{1cm}
  \only<+>{\hfill\beamerbutton{#1}}%
  \only<+>{\hfill\begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true,right]{solucion}#2
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
\end{overlayarea}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{original implementation}
\begin{enumerate}
\item<1-> foo
\item<2-> bar
\item<3-> baz
\item<4-> buzz
\end{enumerate}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{1cm}
\only<5>{\hfill\beamerbutton{How do we get last expression?}}
\only<6>{\hfill\begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true,right]{solucion}
         Using a Taylor series expansion
         $e^t = 1 + t + t^2/2! + t^3/3! + \ldots$
     \end{beamercolorbox}}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{macro implementation}
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
\item foo
\item bar
\item baz
\item buzz
\end{enumerate}
\pregunta{How do we get last expression?}
  {Using a Taylor series expansion $e^t = 1 + t + t^2/2! + t^3/3! + \ldots$}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Then if you use the same style of overlay specification in your slides this will automatically add two more in sequence.

If it were me I would create two overlay-specification-aware environments so I could have something a bit more semantic in the markup (sorry, this doesn't exactly work right now.  I'll have to come back to it later):

```
\newenvironment<>{pregunta}[1]{%
  \begin{onlyenv}#1\hfill\beamerbutton}{%
  \end{onlyenv}
  }
\newenvironment<>{solucion}[1]{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}#1[rounded=true,right]{solucion}}{%
  \end{beamercolorbox}}

\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{1cm}
\begin{pregunta}<+>
  How do we get last expression?
\end{pregunta}
\begin{solucion}<+>
  Using a Taylor series expansion $e^t = 1 + t + t^2/2! + t^3/3! + \ldots$
\end{solucion}
\end{overlayarea}
```

Then you can also use beamer's theme mechanism to style them consistently.

I had thought that you could still hard-code your slide numbers by using the `beamerpauses` counter.  But it seems that this counter is only used when incremental overlay specifcations are.

Comment: Thank you very much. Using auto-increment (<+->) works for me as you say. I wish it could  also be used when I code overlays manually, which sometimes I need to do for more control. But your solution is good enough for most of my uses.

Comment: @F.Tusell: I'm glad it works for you.  You can do a lot with the incremental overlays, including with offsets so you never have to hard-code any numbers.  If I can get my overlay-specification-aware version working you could use either/or.